# highchart select an area to show some info by clicking and drag mouse but not release

Tags: highcharts

I am currently working on the highchart and I wish to implement a feature that when you click mouse and drag it over the chart, a tooltip will show up to indicate the start and end date (x-Axis) of your selection.

Currently, I can only find events.selection, but you need to release the mouse by triggering this event. Is there a way to achieve a "area selection" function without releasing mouse?

Any hint will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: try dragStart event and get point.x to display date of x, will add a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

**Update** While I was looking for the plug-in I used( written by Torstein Hønsi) I got this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/

following code is an example how I used dragging/drop in plotOption

```
  plotOptions : {
                                    series : {
                                        cursor : 'ns-resize',
                                        point : {
                                            events : {

                                                drag : function(e) {

                                                    $('#drag')
                                                            .html(
                                                                    'Dragging <b>'
                                                                            + this.series.name
                                                                            + '</b>, <b>'
                                                                            + this.category
                                                                            + '</b> to <b>'
                                                                            + Highcharts
                                                                                    .numberFormat(
                                                                                            e.newY,
                                                                                            2)
                                                                            + '</b>');
                                                },
                                                drop : function() {
                                                    $('#drop')
                                                            .html(
                                                                    'In <b>'
                                                                            + this.series.name
                                                                            + '</b>, <b>'
                                                                            + this.category
                                                                            + '</b> was set to <b>'
                                                                            + Highcharts
                                                                                    .numberFormat(
                                                                                            this.y,
                                                                                            2)
                                                                            + '</b>');




                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        stickyTracking : false
                                    },
                                    column : {
                                        stacking : 'normal'
                                    }
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/is-there-a-start-pan-zoom-event-t33369/

informative and useful discussion

Comment: Hi Nishith, thanks for you information and I tried this wrap, however, when I try to click and drag my mouse, I got the following error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined. Also, the zoom in event can not be triggered now.

Comment: I remember, I had similar implementation , will try to add that on fiddle

Comment: @SebastianBochan I figured out what is the problem, I changed from p.call(e) to p.call(this.e) and then it works fine. But if I want to get the start and end value on x Axis, is there a way to do that? I tried e.min and e.max but it seems like not working.

Comment: adding a code part in answer becuase in comment code format wont be good here