# highcharts wrapper function for 'drag'

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to write a wrapper function for 'drag' so that when I click mouse and drag the mouse, I can get the min/max value of selected area on xAxis. When I try the following, I can see that e is a MouseEvent, however, I am not able to see e.min and e.max (they are undefined).

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Pointer.prototype, "drag", function(p, e) {
        console.log('drag started');
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.min, e.max);
        p.call(this, e);
    });
```

Does anyone know that is there a way to get the boundary of selected area on xAxis?

Thanks very much!

Comment: didn't it solved your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528010/highchart-select-an-area-to-show-some-info-by-clicking-and-drag-mouse-but-not-re

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi  Not really, the one you described there is about dragging a data point on the chart, however, my question is about to get get zoom in area selected on the chart before releasing mouse. It is more similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/K7pN9/. When you click mouse and drag it, you will see an area that will be zoomed in, but I want to get the desired data before releasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vickychijwani/ckfymb33/2/)

```js
var axisMin = -1, axisMax = -1;

$(function () {
    Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Pointer.prototype, "dragStart", function(p, e) {
        console.log('drag started');
        p.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        // the dragStart function sets this.mouseDownX for you
        // documentation for Axis#toValue() function is here:
        // http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toValue
        axisMin = this.chart.xAxis[0].toValue(this.mouseDownX, 0);
    });

    Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Pointer.prototype, "drag", function(p, e) {
        // e.chartX represents the pixel position of the mouse pointer in the chart
        axisMax = this.chart.xAxis[0].toValue(e.chartX, 0);
        console.log('' + new Date(axisMin) + ' to ' + new Date(axisMax));
        p.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            series: [{
                data: data
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Hi Vicky, Just wondering is there a way to get the date value of tooltip in the 'drag' wrapper function? The reason I ask this is because sometime the axisMax needs to be rounded to be consistent with the date shows on the tooltip. Sometime the rounding result is different. For example, if I drag mouse to somewhere between Friday and Monday, the axisMax will be sometime Saturday.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too, I'm not sure what's causing the error. But you could poke around in the `Highcharts.Pointer` source code here and see if it helps: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/js/parts/Pointer.js#L342

Comment: It could also be caused by padding, margin, etc in the chart since we're converting `e.chartX` which represents a pixel position in the chart area to a timestamp value using `Axis#toValue()`